# Is there a way to fall back to a non-pseudo-class style in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class, css-cascade

If I have a blue div that someone else owns the code for

```css
.stuff {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

And I want it to be red on hover

```css
.stuff:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But then I want to be able to add a class for it to go back to its non-pseudo-class state:

```css
.stuff.otherclass:hover {
  background-color: unset; /* Want blue in this case */
}
```

Is there a CSS option of going back to a pre-pseudo-class state?

Codepen demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyEWww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to roll back the cascade is using the [`revert`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#default) keyword, but it rolls back to another origin.

There is no way to make the 2nd value in the [output of the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#output-of-the-cascade) become the [cascaded value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#cascaded-value), ignoring the winner.

Instead, you can modify your selector and use the [`:not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) pseudo class:

```css
.stuff {
  background-color: blue;
}
.stuff:not(.otherclass):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Or, alternatively, take advantage of `.stuff.otherclass:hover` having more specificity than `.stuff:hover`

```css
.stuff, .stuff.otherclass:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
.stuff:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: `revert` totally worked in the codepen demo up above. From the spec it seems like that shouldn't be the case?

Comment: @mxiong `revert` shouldn't work unless you have some user-level stylesheet with that color. And what browser do you use? Browser support for `revert` is currently negligible.

Comment: I totally lied. The :not workaround should be good enough though for my use case. A little sad that this isn't a spec'd out CSS feature though

Comment: @mxiong: How would you expect such behavior to be specced in the first place? Choosing the next best declaration in the cascade is obviously error-prone. Arbitrarily stripping the :hover from the selector and finding the last declaration with the resulting selector matching the element sounds decent on paper but it wouldn't work in your case since there is no .stuff.otherclass rule. Arbitrarily finding the most specific rule whose selector lacks :hover is just as error-prone because what if the browser finds a rule with an entirely different selector matching the element instead?

Comment: @BoltClock I suppose I was thinking it would specifically cause the current cascade to strip out all rules which match the pseudo-class that it was applied from. So in this case the browser would see `.stuff:hover` with the red color, and then further down in the style sheet the element would also match `.stuff.otherclass:hover` which would have some sort of property that would cause all `:hover` styles to be unset.
So `background: reset` would:
1. Look at the selector's applied pseudoclass
2. Look up the CSS tree to the last time that property was matched without the same pseudoclass.